# Proper way of storing blob images on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I currently have two options to store some images on the blobstore.

I have a User model `class User(db.Model)` ,where I am saving an avatar for the user. 
One option is to save the avatar as `blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()`  and then serve the image with get_serving_url from the user.avatar reference.

```
class User(db.Model):
    avatar = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()

url = get_serving_url(user.avatar)
```

The other option is to get the path to the image with `get_serving_url()` and save it in the User model as LinkProperty and later just use this link to serve the image.

```
url = get_serving_url(image_file)
class User(db.Model):
    avatar = db.LinkProperty()
```

Is there a significant difference in the two approaches and if yes, what is preferable ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store both. The `BlobReference` to be able to delete the actual blob and the URL in order to avoid calling every time the `get_serving_url()`, which can be potentially slow. The URL that is returned by [`get_serving_url()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url) is unchangeable unless the [`delete_serving_url()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_delete_serving_url) is called, in case it needed to be reseted since that URL is public but unguessable.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, get_serving_url is potentially slow, so storing the URL will help your page load faster.

Comment: @scroll_lock I forgot to mention that if you just starting.. you should consider using `ndb` instead of `db`.. It's the latest and greatest version which has lots of features.. more here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

Answer (score 1):

You should save both references in your model. You use the blobReferenceProperty to reference the latest version of the blob for maintenance (delete and update) and the url for serving the image, because you only need to get the serving url once.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BlobReferenceProperty`. If you store the serving_url you cannot really delete the blob since you don't have any reference to it.